# CoffeeScript Default Arguments

Tags: coffeescript

I'm looking at the following example from [CoffeeScript: Accelerated Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript)

```
x = true
showAnswer = (x = x) ->
  console.log if x then 'It works!' else 'Nope.'

console.log "showAnswer()", showAnswer()
console.log "showAnswer(true)", showAnswer(true)
console.log "showAnswer(false)", showAnswer(false)
```

I don't understand why `showAnswer(...) undefined` shows up for each test.

```
Nope.
showAnswer() undefined
It works!
showAnswer(true) undefined
Nope.
showAnswer(false) undefined
```

Please explain the output of each case.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to define `x = true` prior to your function if you want to give it a default value. `(x = true) ->` is a valid (and I think preferred) method signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that CoffeeScript, by default, returns the last statement in a function. So what your `showAnswer` function actually says is:

```
showAnswer = (x = x) ->
    return console.log if x then 'It works!' else 'Nope.'
```

or compiled to JavaScript:

```
showAnswer = function(x) {
  if (x == null) {
    x = x;
  }
  return console.log(x ? 'It works!' : 'Nope.');
};
```

The other thing to realize is that the `console.log` method returns `undefined`. So when you log the result of your `showAnswer` method, it will print `undefined`.

If I understand your intention correctly, I would modify your original function to do this:

```
showAnswer = (x = x) ->
  if x then 'It works!' else 'Nope.'
```

Alternatively, modify your `console.log` statements as such:

```
console.log "showAnswer()"
showAnswer()

console.log "showAnswer(true)"
showAnswer(true)

console.log "showAnswer(false)"
showAnswer(false)
```